# Need to read one character at time until 10 characters reached

Tags: c#

I am working on a homework assignment, beginning C#.

Have to accept input from user:

- phone number with numbers or characters
- then return only the numeric version of number.

My program takes input and returns value, but does not end when 10 characters have been entered.
You can enter as many characters as you want, then when enter is pressed it only displays first 10.
It also does not test the cases after each character entered. Seems to do at the end.
I would like to have each character tested after input and then once ten characters have been entered
the program display results.

I hope I am giving enough info. I am pretty stressed about this.
It is due tomorrow and I have a few other programs to do yet.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
        do
        {
            int temp = Console.Read();
            input = Convert.ToChar(temp);
            //int tempInput = Convert.ToString(tempInput);
            switch (input)
            {
                case '0':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    counter--;
                    break;
// { other cases }
                default:
                    // if input does not match cases then loop returns to 
                    // request new input
                    Display.Error(input.ToString());
                    Console.Write(alphaNumericPhoneNumber);
                    //Display.Continue();
                    //Console.Clear();
                    input = ' ';
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (numericPhoneNumber.Length < 0);
        return numericPhoneNumber;
    }
```

Comment: *"I am pretty stressed about this. It is due tomorrow and I have a few other programs to do yet"* Hehe, been there mate - that was like every single uni assignment for me. Always got there though.

Comment: @RPM1984 This is all the fun of student life.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - absolutely! Well i guess i payed the price for skipping all the lectures in favor of pool/beer at the student pub. :)

Comment: check my answer is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for the `Console.Read()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) explains the described behavior.

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it terminates when you press the Enter key. [...] Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character at a time.

If you want to process the characters as they arrive, you may use the `KeyAvailable`and `ReadKey` methods as [demonstrated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) in the documentation. The example is available in 5 .NET languages, including C#.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I used ReadKey and it worked well. It is a little outside of the scope of what we have learned so far... but i think the Prof will be fine with it. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to use `Console.ReadKey()` instead of `Console.Read()` as the latter expects a `\n` from an `ENTER` press to return and the former returns immediately when key is pressed.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadPhone();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ReadPhone()
        {
            var numericPhoneNumber = string.Empty;

            Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
            do
            {
                var keyInfo= Console.ReadKey();
                if (char.IsDigit(keyInfo.KeyChar))
                {
                    numericPhoneNumber += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter numeric numbers only");
                }
            }
            while (numericPhoneNumber.Length <= 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Phone Number: {0}", numericPhoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    int i=0;
    string str=String.Empty;
    Char c;            
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
    while (i < 10)
    {
       if (char.IsDigit(c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar))
       {
            str += c;
            i++;
       }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("str: "+str); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not so sure about helping you with your homework. I used to sell my assignments to other kids when I was studying, so I guess I can't take the moral high ground here.

Here's a solution, but make sure you do some googling and understand how it works.

```
// Initialise the result to nothing.
string result = string.Empty;

do
{
    // Prompt for input.
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your 10-digit phone number: ");

    // Read the response.
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Replace any characters that are not numbers with the empty string (remove them).
    result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);
}
while (result.Length != 10);

// Do something with the result.
Console.WriteLine("You typed: '{0}'.", result);
```

If you want to read one character at a time (which sounds a bit odd to me), then you could do something like:

```
// Initialise the result to nothing.
string result = string.Empty;

// Prompt for input.
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your 10-digit phone number: "); 

do
{
    string input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();

    // Replace any characters that are not numbers with the empty string (remove them).
    result += Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);         
}
while (result.Length != 10);

// Do something with the result.
Console.WriteLine("You typed: '{0}'.", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your help.
I ended up using the readkey to evaluate each character and assign its respective numerical value as per the telephone keypad.
I don't think that I was very clear about it in my original post... little stressed about it at the time... spent to long on this question.
The replies to this post showed some pretty clean code. I hope to get to that level soon.
I will show what I ended up doing, just incase someone in interested.
Thanks again for your help.

```
 class Request
    {
        public static void GetPhoneNumber(out string UserInput, out string ConvertedString)
        {
            // create instance of ConsoleKeyInfo
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
```

`string alphaNumericPhoneNumber = " ";
        string numericPhoneNumber = " ";
        char input = ' ';
        Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
        // perform a do... while loop to read 10 characters of input
        do
        {                
            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            input =  cki.KeyChar;                
            switch (char.ToUpper(input))
            {
                case '0':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    break;
                case '1':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();                        
                    break;
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                case '2':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "2";                        
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                case '3':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "3";                        
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                case '4':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "4";                        
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                case '5':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "5";                        
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                case '6':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "6";                        
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                case '7':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "7";                        
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                case '8':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "8";                        
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                case '9':
                    alphaNumericPhoneNumber += input.ToString();
                    numericPhoneNumber += "9";                        
                    break;
                default:
                    // if input does not match cases then loop returns to 
                    // request new input
                    Console.Clear();
                    Display.Error(input.ToString());
                    // display for user to continue... displays valid numbers so far
                    Console.Write("Continue with phone number: " + alphaNumericPhoneNumber);                        
                    input = ' '; // returns blank character and not added to strings so not counted
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (numericPhoneNumber.Length < 11); // counts until string has 10 digits
        UserInput = alphaNumericPhoneNumber;
        ConvertedString = numericPhoneNumber;
    }

}`